# Display custom_post_type with current taxonmy of a page

Tags: pages, taxonomy

I've associated a taxonomy to pages and a custom_post_type.

When i'm on a page with a said taxonomy term, I need to display a list of custom_post_type associated twith the same term.

I'm using this:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'offres', //my CPT
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'cible', //my Custom Taxonomy
                'field' => 'id',
                'include_children' => false,
            )
        )
    );
    $_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($_query->have_posts()):
        while ($_query->have_posts()):
            $_query->the_post();

            the_title();
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_query();?>
```

I need to get the current taxonomy term or id from the page, how do I this?

Comment: Do not run a custom query, just use the default loop in order to display the correct posts from the main query

Comment: I don't think I understand hom i'm supposed to use the default loop here. I've tried a lot of ways but nothing gets me the result I want, do you have an exemple?

Answer (score 0):

use some thing like this

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
```

Most probably `$term_id` should give the id of the taxonomy term of the current page, try `echo $term_id;`

If it doesn't then try  using var_dump() like

```
echo "<pre>";var_dump( $queried_object )echo "</pre>";
```

Analyse the output , and use it according to your need